# Livetime object URL

Tags: url, facebook-opengraph

How long should / must the object URL (og:url) be available? Only for the time I send the action to Facebook or longer / for ever?

Ralph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, your object URLs should exist for the lifetime of your product - hopefully indefinitely.

However, if facebook cannot retrieve metadata for your URL it will continue to use the last-seen metadata.